# Android Studio - Generate Signed APK : Image loading issues

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, startapp

there is this problem that is diving me crazy today.
I recently finished my first Android mobile app, though it was working just fine when I was Running in in my Phone inside Android studio. But once I Generated Signed APK file and installed it in my phone, I had these problems : 
 -> in the splash screen, Im supposed to see a StartAPP ad, but its saying  : "Webpage not available" it looks like its floating over the screen( I am using both StartApp & Admob ads - I am using a webview in the screen ) .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHnLB.png)
 -> one more thing, is the pictures. The app has only loaded 2 pictures from 20 pictures in my drawable directory.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQnLu.png)

Answer (score 0):

For the first thing, I fixed it by disabling the Splash StartApp ad with        **StartAppAd.disableSplash();**
, though the second thing about uploading images properly still doesnt work :/ HELP PLEASE

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem, I just fixed it 
**HOW ?**

 - well, I tool my generated apk file, and then I decompiled it using 'Easy APK Tool' and then I added my drawable missing pictures, and re-compiled it.

Now the app is ready :-)